# What type of tool has rings of teeth that spin freely on a shaft?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

All "gears" spin independently of each other. Stumped my pops, hasn't happened in my lifetime. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does the swivel near the handle swing or is it locked?

Comment: Where did you find it? Was it with a genre of tools like woodworking, plumbing, electrical, etc...?

Comment: that is used for perforating the surface of something ... possibly wallpaper so that it can be soaked before removal ... maybe for dimpling wood surface so that glue holds better

Comment: @jsotola    The teeth are not sharpe  like perforator teeth

Comment: are there any markings on the tool?

Comment: i have a suspicion that it is a tool for leatherwork

Comment: perhaps a texturing tool? leather, soft wood, etc..?

Comment: Clay texturing?

Comment: possibly used with tracing paper to mark fabric

Comment: Wow! what a lot of creative explanations!

Comment: @EdBeal I wouldn't use that thing anywhere near food.  Especially since those gears are all separately moving parts, I'd imagine gunk would get in there and it'd be impossible to clean.  I have seen tools like that for dough, but they're fixed, as one single part.

Comment: What you do in your bedroom is none of our business.  Put that thing away in your sock drawer where it belongs!

Answer (score 19):

From a German website: [Russka](https://www.russka.de/ratgeber/ratgeber-gelenke-schuetzen)

> Dermapuncture anti-pain roller
> This massage method can promote blood circulation, relax muscles and thus relieve pain. The uniaxial Dermapuncture anti-pain roller 100 has 560 silver-plated needle tips and is used for smaller parts of the body and joints, such as: B. forehead, temples, neck, shoulders, hand, joints and for foot reflexology massage.

The two-axis Dermapuncture anti-pain roller 200 has 1360 silver-plated needle tips and is used in full-body massage.

Article no.executionPZN73030 100Anti pain roller 1000272151973030 200Anti pain roller 20003885097

[image]
[image]

Comment: wow, and how did you figure it out?

Comment: Reverse image search with Google Lens.

Comment: Aha! Yes I know you can find "similar images" but didn't know how to do it with your own upload, or in this case, the camera/app. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: being that we know now this tool is nothing to do with diy, is there a better stack this can be moved to?